# PyInstaller myscript.py - issues: empty dist folder

Tags: qgis, python, osgeo4w

This question is subsequent to another question: [here.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185860/creating-executables-from-python-using-osgeo4w-shell) The question was solved but I ran into another issue and tried to ask it there but it is worth being its own question I think.

Python version in OSGeo4W.bat the version number is "Python 2.7.5 (Default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32".

I want to make my python script "a.py" into a .exe for distribution.

The start of a.py looks like this:

```
import sys
import os
import math
path = os.environ['PATH']
pgdal= 'C:\\Program Files\\QGIS Lyon\\share\\gdal;'
os.environ['GDAL_DATA']='C:\\Program Files\\QGIS Lyon\\share\\gdal\\gdal-data'
os.environ['GDAL_DRIVER_PATH']='C:\\Program Files\\QGIS Lyon\\share\\gdal\\gdalplugins'
os.environ['PROJ_LIB']='C:\\Program Files\\QGIS Lyon\\share\\gdal\\projlib'
os.environ['PATH'] = "%s;%s" % (pgdal, path)
try:
    from osgeo import osr
    from osgeo import gdal
except ImportError:
    import osr
    import gdal
```

I used OSGeo4W.bat to run, which was successful:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

In OsGeo4w.bat shell ran as admin, I ran the following commands (only did this once):

```
SET "PATH="C:\Program Files\QGIS Lyon\share\gdal";%PATH%"
SET "GDAL_DATA=C:\Program Files\QGIS Lyon\share\gdal\gdal-data"
SET "GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=C:\Program Files\QGIS Lyon\share\gdal\gdalplugins"
SET "PROJ_LIB=C:\Program Files\QGIS Lyon\share\gdal\projlib"
```

Then in the shell I ran:

```
cd C:\Python27\PyPack
```

then to attempt to create my executable:

```
pyinstaller a.py
```

The output was an addition of 3 items in C:\Python27\PyPack:

```
> 1) C:\Python27\PyPack\build\a\a.exe.manifest - (this is the only file)
> 2) C:\Python27\PyPack\dist - (empty) 
> 3) C:\Python27\PyPack\a.spec
```

The output in the shell is:

```
    c:\Python27\PyPack>pyinstaller a.py 
1344 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.1.1
1344 INFO: Python: 2.7.5 
1344 INFO: Platform: Windows-8-6.2.9200 
1344 INFO: wrote c:\Python27\PyPack\a.spec 
1360 INFO: UPX is not available. 
1360 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths ['c:\\Python27\\PyPack', 'c:\\Python27\\PyPack'] 
1360 INFO: checking Analysis 
1360 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent 
1360 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph... 
1360 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks... 
1486 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc 
1581 INFO: Adding Microsoft.VC90.CRT to dependent assemblies of final executable   required by c:\progra~1\qgisly~1\bin\python.exe 
2831 INFO: Found C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_18f8a87fd1919cd9.manifest 
2845 INFO: Found C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_3da38fdebd0e6822.manifest 
2861 INFO: Found C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4148_none_acd0e4ffe1daef0a.manifest 
2878 INFO: Found C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_acd388d7e1d8689f.manifest 
2893 INFO: Found C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9177_none_acd40623e1d81331.manifest 
3003 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9177_none ... 
3003 INFO: Found manifest C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9177_none_08e695a3a83b6ce3.manifest 
3003 INFO: Searching for file msvcr90.dll 
3003 INFO: Found file C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9177_none_08e695a3a83b6ce3\msvcr90.dll 
3003 INFO: Searching for file msvcp90.dll 
3003 INFO: Found file C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9177_none_08e695a3a83b6ce3\msvcp90.dll 
3018 INFO: Searching for file msvcm90.dll 
3018 INFO: Found file C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9177_none_08e695a3a83b6ce3\msvcm90.dll 
3111 INFO: Found C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_18f8a87fd1919cd9.manifest 
3111 INFO: Found C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_3da38fdebd0e6822.manifest
3111 INFO: Found C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4148_none_acd0e4ffe1daef0a.manifest 
3111 INFO: Found C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_acd388d7e1d8689f.manifest
3128 INFO: Found C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9177_none_acd40623e1d81331.manifest 
3128 INFO: Adding redirect Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8)

    -> (9, 0, 30729, 9177) 
4299 INFO: Analyzing c:\Python27\PyPack\a.py 
7972 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils 
8347 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   _xmlplus 
13473 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site 
13488 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISLY~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules' 
13565 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com 
15957 INFO: Looking for import hooks ... 
15988 INFO: Processing hook   hook-distutils.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in
    _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in
    _run_code
        exec code in run_globals   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 90, in run
        run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
        PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 755, in main
        build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 701, in build
        exec(text, spec_namespace)   
File "<string>", line 16, in <module>   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 212, in __init__
        self.__postinit__()   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 183, in __postinit__
        self.assemble()   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 434, in assemble
        imphook_object.update_dependencies(self.graph)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 309, in update_dependencies
        self._process_datas(mod_graph)   
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 285, in _process_datas
        self.datas.update(set(format_binaries_and_datas(self._module.datas)))  
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 426, in format_binaries_and_datas
        src_root_path_or_glob)) PyInstaller.compat.FileNotFoundError: Path or glob "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\Include\pyconfig.h" not found or matches no files.

    c:\Python27\PyPack>
```

The file `a.spec`has the following text:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['a.py'],
             pathex=['c:\\Python27\\PyPack'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=None,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='a',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='a')
```

Can someone please help me decipher the output so I can get a.py into a .exe?

Answer (score 1):

I finally achieved what I set out to, but I still don't understand why the problem happened, except that PyInstaller did not like importing gdal.

Originally (as stated in the question), the top of my a.py script looked like this:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import sys
import os
import math

path = os.environ['PATH']
pgdal= 'C:\\Program Files\\QGIS Lyon\\share\\gdal;'
os.environ['GDAL_DATA']='C:\\Program Files\\QGIS Lyon\\share\\gdal\\gdal-data'
os.environ['GDAL_DRIVER_PATH']='C:\\Program Files\\QGIS Lyon\\share\\gdal\\gdalplugins'
os.environ['PROJ_LIB']='C:\\Program Files\\QGIS Lyon\\share\\gdal\\projlib'
os.environ['PATH'] = "%s;%s" % (pgdal, path)

try:
    from osgeo import osr
    from osgeo import gdal
except ImportError:
    import osr
    import gdal
```

But now, I changed it to look like this:

```
 ##try:
from osgeo import osr
    ##from osgeo import gdal
 ##except ImportError:
    ##import osr
    ##import gdal
```

Hence, I commented out all gdal import statements and only left `from osgeo import osr`. I tested all other combinations of these import statements and only `from osgeo import osr` works for me.

My a.py script (with the original import statements i.e. importing gdal) works fine when ran in Python but it's just PyInstaller that doesn't like it.
I would really love to understand why pyinstaller doesn't like importing gdal for me.

Comment: Glad you found some sort of a solution =)