# QGIS snap question

Tags: qgis, layers, snapping

I have only recently started using QGIS with no previous knowledge of it so I still struggle with the most basic functions. In particular, I need some help with the snap function.
I'm currently employing QGIS to represent a natural gas distribution network for a small city. To do this, I have a line layer consisting of segments representing the actual pipes and a point layer representing every single user connected to the gas grid (which I geocoded from a .csv file with the MMQGIS plugin). The points in the point layer are located according to the address of the user, and thus slightly shifted with respect to the lines, which mostly run along the city streets (see image attached). For the purpose of my work, I need to "attach" every point in the point layer to the closest line in the line layer, simulating the connection between the network and the users. As far as I know, the snap function should be able to perform this task, but I have not been able to operate it properly so far.
My question is, how do I snap a point layer to a line layer in such a way that every point snaps to the vertex/vertices of the closest line?

[image]
EDIT
I'm using the latest release of QGIS which would be 2.18.3 with GRASS 7.2.0.

Comment: ... but unfortunately not yet impemented in the stable release.

Comment: Any chance to get the qgis-dev version from OSGEO4W?

Comment: I gave an answer with PyQGIS in:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237224/aligning-multiple-points-to-line-in-qgis