# Snapping points to the nearest street?

Tags: gdal, grass-gis, general-transit-feed-specification

I have a .shp with all the street of an area. I also have all the gtfs of the public transportation of the area so I want to clean the gtfs data of the itinerary. The shape of all the itinerary are a bounch of point with the coordinates and some of this is in some building so i want to take all the shape's points and put on the street. I can use Grass or Gdal. Suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237224/aligning-multiple-points-to-line-in-qgis , but only working in QGIS 3.0 which is still beta.

Comment: If you know about gdal or GRASS what have you tried so far?

Comment: @AndreJ this function is already available in version 2.14, just without the 'behavior' - option; http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_geometry_snapper.html

Comment: @LaughU I can use on the project but I don't know how to use them to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can relax your dependence on GRASS/GDAL, there is a [Python script](https://github.com/HSLdevcom/gtfs_shape_mapfit/blob/fastmapmatch/fit_gtfs.bash) that does this with OpenStreetMap data.

Comment: Glad I could be of some help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the procedure I use in GRASS to snap points to lines. It uses the `v.distance` module to get the target coords for snapping to the lines. Suppose we have a points vector "stations" and a line vector "streams", and the new snapped points will be "new_stations" :

```
# Add columns to the original points to hold the snapp coords
v.db.addcolumn --q map=stations columns="snap_x double, snap_y double"
v.distance --q --o from=stations to=streams output=connectors upload=to_x,to_y column=snap_x,snap_y
# Create a new stations vector with the snap_x and snap_y columns 
# Use v.out.ascii with -r option to export only drainage point in current region (domain)
# snap_x and snap_y columns become the X-Y coordinates for frxst_pts point vector
v.out.ascii --q -r -c stations columns="id,station_name,station_num,longitude,latitude,snap_x,snap_y" separator=comma | v.in.ascii --q --o input=- output=new_stations x=8 y=9 cat=3 columns="east double,north double,id integer,station_name text,station_num integer,longitude double,latitude double,snap_x double,snap_y double" separator=comma skip=1
```

HTH