# Points in one line

Tags: qgis

Do you know how to make points in one line? They are set up unprofessional.
[image]

Comment: A bit more information on what exactly you try to achieve would be useful. Right now I have no real idea, what you are doing, especially in which window/tool of QGis.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237224/aligning-multiple-points-to-line-in-qgis

Comment: You can check this URL

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

You can use special plugins to transform points to one line. For example:

1. [ReconstructLine](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/reconstruct_line/)
2. [Points2One](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/points2one/)

Search plugins at [plugins page](https://plugins.qgis.org/).

If you need to snap points to straight line just draw such line and enable [snapping](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#setting-the-snapping-tolerance-and-search-radius).

[image]